# auto populating infopath forms from SQL Server Database

Tags: 2007, infopath, forms-services

We are using Infopath Forms to store and manage our server documentation. A lot of the information there is already drawn from the devices (memory, CPU, network adapters etc), and stored in a separate SQL Server 2005 database that is always up to date. Is there any way to retrieve the data and update our forms automatically each time the database changes or at certain predefined times?

Comment: Does the form submits to SharePoint List or Form Library? Is it a default list form or a template for Form Library?

Comment: Thank you. The information is stored based on a form template, inside a form library.